# X-Server broke after I tried to configure a theme in Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, xorg, lightdm, xfce

It's definitely user-specific, because `lightdm` works ok, and if I choose a guest account rather than my own account, the X-server loads without problems at all. In fact, that's what I'm using now, otherwise I'd had to use `links` to post this.

The problem is I can't log in to my main account. Or rather, I can't use the graphical interface after logging in.

All I see if I do that is a blue screen (well, teal actually) and the mouse pointer, which I can move around,  but other than that, nothing happens.

Before this happened, I saw that the Greybird theme I've always used didn't look like anything it was supposed to (and did a few minutes before that). So I decided to tweak it in the Theme Configuration. It worked, until I clicked custom menu colors. That was when the graphical interface froze.

[What I did on my main account before X-server crashed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od8k5.jpg)

I restarted the X-server by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+Backspace`, and that was when I saw an empty screen. I rebooted then, but nothing changed.

The X-server is still usable, but not with my main account.

I don't think touching `/etc/` files is a good idea in this situation. It's not a system-wide problem after all. The problem is in some config file, but I don't know which one, as I've never edited them by hand, I only used built-in tools for theme configuration.

### UPD:

I used `ls -latr` to see what files were edited last, and renamed `gtk.css` in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/` to `gtk.css.bk`. After that, something changed. The behavior is essentially the same, only it's not the blue (or teal) screen anymore, it's the standard wallpaper I used. But nothing else loads and no hotkeys work (except `Ctrl+Alt+1 .. Ctrl+Alt+7`).

### UPD 2:

Files `~/.xsession-errors` and `~/.xsession-errors.old` have this:

```
    openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
    cannot connect to brltty at :0
    upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still not completely sure why this worked, but deleting `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xsettings.xml` (or rather renaming it to `xsettings.xml.bk`) fixed the problem.  And not just this problem, it also fixed the broken theme I was trying to fix with editing.

This is what this file used to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<channel name="xsettings" version="1.0">
  <property name="Net" type="empty">
    <property name="ThemeName" type="string" value="Greybird"/>
    <property name="IconThemeName" type="string" value="elementary-xfce-darker"/>
    <property name="DoubleClickTime" type="empty"/>
    <property name="DoubleClickDistance" type="empty"/>
    <property name="DndDragThreshold" type="empty"/>
    <property name="CursorBlink" type="empty"/>
    <property name="CursorBlinkTime" type="empty"/>
    <property name="SoundThemeName" type="empty"/>
    <property name="EnableEventSounds" type="bool" value="false"/>
    <property name="EnableInputFeedbackSounds" type="bool" value="false"/>
  </property>
  <property name="Xft" type="empty">
    <property name="DPI" type="empty"/>
    <property name="Antialias" type="int" value="1"/>
    <property name="Hinting" type="int" value="1"/>
    <property name="HintStyle" type="empty"/>
    <property name="RGBA" type="empty"/>
    <property name="Lcdfilter" type="empty"/>
  </property>
  <property name="Gtk" type="empty">
    <property name="CanChangeAccels" type="bool" value="false"/>
    <property name="ColorPalette" type="empty"/>
    <property name="FontName" type="empty"/>
    <property name="IconSizes" type="empty"/>
    <property name="KeyThemeName" type="empty"/>
    <property name="ToolbarStyle" type="string" value="icons"/>
    <property name="ToolbarIconSize" type="empty"/>
    <property name="MenuImages" type="bool" value="true"/>
    <property name="ButtonImages" type="bool" value="true"/>
    <property name="MenuBarAccel" type="empty"/>
    <property name="CursorThemeName" type="empty"/>
    <property name="CursorThemeSize" type="empty"/>
    <property name="DecorationLayout" type="empty"/>
    <property name="ColorScheme" type="string" value="selected_bg_color:#398ee7;selected_fg_color:#eeeeee;"/>
  </property>
</channel>
```

The reason I decided to delete this file was that my guest account didn't have it. Initially, I was only going to copy all of my guest settings (I have an actual user named `guest` rather than a standard guest account, so it has its own home directory). But when I started comparing my files, I noticed that quite a few of them only exist on my main account. Which is when I tried to remove some of them. The `xsettings.xml` seemed the most suspicious to me because of its many empty values (although I kept in mind it was entirely possible they needed to be empty).

The moment I renamed it and restarted `lightdm`, I could log in to my main account, and the X-server loaded without problems. However, it is not the only file I subjected to this treatment. It is entirely possible that this solution only worked because I have renamed the other file, `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`. I also copied `~/.gtkrc-2.0` to `~/.gtkrc-2.0.bk`, but it definitely wasn't what helped because I didn't remove the original file.

I didn't do anything else, other than trying to diagnose and backtrack the problem. Which I think paid off.

I am not sure what exactly caused this problem because I didn't edit the files until I already experienced it. It might be a glitch in the Theme Configuration GUI, because that's what caused the X-Server to freeze in the first place. Either way, if the same thing happens to you, I recommend that you keep at least two accounts (one of which you don't normally use) so that you could compare your configuration files, and if you don't, try renaming `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xsettings.xml` to something else. It might just solve your problem.